# Auto-translation of newline characters in the terminal

Tags: linux, shell, text-processing, command-line, terminal

I'm following along [here](https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/02.enteringRawMode.html).

I notice (this is not complete, just for demonstration) that at this point:

```
#include <termios.h>

  raw.c_iflag &= ~(ICRNL | IXON);
  raw.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
  raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
```

makes it so something like:

```
printf("\n");
```

simply advances to the next line without moving the cursor to the beginning. The text explains that typically `\n` gets translated to `\r\n` and `OPOST` disables this.

Relatedly, the `ICNRL` flag makes it so carraige returns (via `^M`) are correctly received by the terminal.

The manual is unenlightening:

> OPOST  Enable implementation-defined output processing.

Can someone explain the history, and what is going on here, in more detail?

How is it that `\n` is a single-byte then when doing a hexdump on files? Is the "auto-translation" to `\r\n` something that is done purely on a view-basis, and not actually for the bytes in text?

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered slightly further along in the tutorial at [Turn off all output processing](https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/02.enteringRawMode.html#turn-off-all-output-processing)

> It turns out that the terminal does a similar translation on the output side. It translates each newline ("\n") we print into a carriage return followed by a newline ("\r\n"). The terminal requires both of these characters in order to start a new line of text. The carriage return moves the cursor back to the beginning of the current line, and the newline moves the cursor down a line, scrolling the screen if necessary. (These two distinct operations originated in the days of typewriters and teletypes.)

To answer your question directly,

> How is it that \n is a single-byte then when doing a hexdump on files? Is the "auto-translation" to \r\n something that is done purely on a view-basis, and not actually for the bytes in text?

Yes. Each instance of `\n` is converted to `\r\n` by the terminal line discipline when sent to the terminal. You can turn that post-processing off with the `opost` flag. At the shell level this can be managed through `stty`

```
stty -opost    # Turn off "opost" processing
ls             # Notice you get a ladder effect due to there being no CR actions
stty opost     # Restore "opost" processing
```

If you are going to experiment with `stty`, it's worth knowing that you can save the current state for later restoration:

```
g=$(stty -g)    # Save current state
stty raw        # Interesting times ahead
…
stty $g         # Follow this with « Ctrl j » rather than « Enter »
```

If you're using `bash` this won't work quite as you might expect, since it offers command line editing (GNU `readline`). Drop into a different shell such as `dash` (`sh`) for the true effect to manifest.

Comment: So to be clear, the `LF` control character corresponds to `\n`, but `\n` by convention is translated to `CR` + `LF`, unless you turn off `opost`, in which case, it treats `\n` as `LF`.

Comment: Actually, I learned typewriting in the days of mechanical typewriters, but I never met one where the carriage return (not a key, but a lever!) did not produce a line feed at the same time. No distinct operations. Also, the symbol on CR keys includes the down part of LF. There is a reason to separate both movements, but I think referring to typewriters is misleading.

Comment: @Philippos-prostrike- I also learned to type (in a fashion) on a typewriter. Consider the difference between rolling the patten up one line and returning to the beginning of the line. Separate operations that were "merged" by the newline lever. Printers also separated linefeed and cartridge return as did teletypes, as they had separate mechanical operations for CR and LF. Lots of history here

Comment: @user129393192 yes!